# How can I fix the residual plot though transformation

Tags: regression, anova, residuals, transform

What transformation can I use to fix this residual plot (make the red line horizontal). I tried square root, log, 1/y, and squared. None of them helped.

[image: residual plot]

The data is of a 2 way ANOVA:
Response Variable = time (in minutes) to teach a chimp a sign.
Number of observations             = 4 x 10 = 40

1. Response variable = time (in minutes)
2. Factor 1          = Sign (10 levels)
3. Factor 2          = Chimpanzee (4 levels)

---

Time,           Sign,      Chimp

```
178              1         1
 60              2         1
177              3         1
 36              4         1
225              5         1
345              6         1
 40              7         1
  2              8         1
287              9         1
 14             10         1

 78              1         2
 14              2         2
 80              3         2
 15              4         2
 10              5         2
115              6         2
 10              7         2
 12              8         2
129              9         2
 80             10         2

 99              1         3
 18              2         3
 20              3         3
 25              4         3
 15              5         3
 54              6         3
 25              7         3
 10              8         3
476              9         3
 56             10         3

297              1         4
 20              2         4
195              3         4
 18              4         4
 24              5         4
420              6         4
 40              7         4
 15              8         4
372              9         4
190             10         4
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell.  Could you explain what the variables mean, give some brief summaries of the data characteristics, and tell us what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Nonaparametric smoothing regression?

Comment: @whuber just edited in the data set

Comment: By default, you ought to consider analyzing logarithms of response times, as [Fechner's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber%E2%80%93Fechner_law) suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log transformation does not look bad:
[image]

Further, the log transformation is fairly clearly indicated by $\lambda=0$ within the Box-Cox family of transformations:
[image]